# Viewpager with Fragments without FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I need to use the ViewPager with Fragments to manage the Layouts. I cannot use FragmentPagerAdapter because my android's version does not support it. I tried with PagerAdapter but it shows only the static layouts.

Is there any way to use Fragment inside ViewPager without using FragmentPagerAdapter?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add some more details about your app, what is the targetSDK? and minimum SDK?

Comment: Actually this is a custom version of android auto sdk (only for car maker) but most of the functions are however supported like ViewPager, PageAdapter and so on... it has his own Fragments that are not supported by FragmentPagerAdapter so I can't use it.... is it possible to find another way in Android to do this in order to try?

Comment: Interesting, you may need to add this information to the question to offer more context (the more information you can provide to help future readers, the more likely you'll receive an answer)